# How to added values in grouped column/rows using Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I need some help in getting the table final_price values added to each other where the customer_name/customer_id is the same so the row count becomes 3 so example: the customer named Hass H final_price would be:

417 + 21 = 438 on one row

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/29cb5/13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grouping sets`.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT c.first_name || ' ' || c.surname AS customer_name, 
       SUM(oi.quantity) AS number_of_items_bought,
       SUM(sp.price * oi.quantity) AS final_price
FROM customers c JOIN
     ordered_items oi
     ON oi.customers_id = c.id JOIN
     store_products sp
     ON sp.id = oi.store_products_id
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (customer_name, sp.price), (customer_name) );
```

Note that I removed the `HAVING` (which didn't seem to be doing anything) and modified the second `SUM()` as well.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/29cb5/37/0) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I been looking for just little changed yours removed the WHERE clause as well and the grouping set

this is what I was missing and I done this wrong ```SUM(sp.price * oi.quantity) AS final_price```

here is the SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/29cb5/46

Comment: @Mohamed . . . I removed the `where` clause.  I didn't understand its purpose, but it was in the fiddle.